# JAVA, передача папки через socket

Tags: java

Какой путь надо указать, чтобы передать папку через socket?

Сервер:

```
package aaa;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        ServerSocket serversocket = null;
        try {

            serversocket  = new ServerSocket(8903);

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            socket = serversocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;

        try {
            in = socket.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Андрей\\Desktop\\1.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("фАЙЛА НЕ СУЩЕСТВУЕТ");
        }

        byte[] b = new byte[20*1024];

        int i ;

        while((i = in.read(b)) >0){
            out.write(b, 0, i);
        }
    out.close();
    in.close();
    socket.close();
    serversocket.close();

    }

}
```

Клиент:

```
package aaa;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class socket {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        Socket client = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8903);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Андрей\\Desktop\\1.txt"));
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[8192];
        int in;
        while ((in = bis.read(byteArray)) != -1){
            bos.write(byteArray,0,in);
        }
        bis.close();
        bos.close();    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FileInputStream` и `FileOutputStream` работают с конкретным файлом, а не с папкой. Соответственно нет никакого "специального" пути, который вычитал и передал бы папку целиком.

Вам нужно последовательно прочитать каждый файл в папке и передать его на сервер, попутно передавая метаданные файла, например, его имя (чтобы знать куда его записать на сервере).

Как вариант, вы можете попробовать использовать формат zip как промежуточный контейнер для группы файлов. Попробуйте обернуть `client.getOutputStream()` в [`ZipOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) на клиенте, а на сервере для распаковки оберните `socket.getInputStream()` в [`ZipInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html).

Comment: при копирование папки отказ в доступе