# Как передать файл от сервера к клиенту

Tags: java

хочу передать от сервера к клиенту текстовый файл при получении вывести его на консоль клиента. Использую class File - не получается. Вот исходники:

```
public class VServerThreads {
    private static ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2222);
                System.out.println("Initialized");
//            waiting for a client
                while (true) {
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    System.out.println(socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " connected");
//                creating a new thread for a new client
                    VServer vServer = new VServer(socket);
                    new Thread(vServer).start();
                }
            }finally {
                if(!serverSocket.isClosed()) {
                    serverSocket.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}



class VServer implements Runnable {
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private static AtomicInteger userNumIncrement;
    private int userNum = 0;

    private static List<Document> documentsList;
    private static List<File> filesList;

    static {
        userNumIncrement = new AtomicInteger(0);
    }

    public VServer(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        userNum = userNumIncrement.incrementAndGet();
        clientSocket = socket;
        documentsList = new ArrayList<>();
        filesList = new ArrayList<>();

        documentsList.add(new Document(75, "Ulysses", 13.20));
        documentsList.add(new Document(75, "Moby Dick", 15.70));
        documentsList.add(new Document(110, "Hamlet", 18.10));
        documentsList.add(new Document(110, "The Odyssey", 18.30));
        documentsList.add(new Document(130, "Great Gatsby", 20.10));
        documentsList.add(new Document(130, "Divine Comedy", 21.15));
        documentsList.add(new Document(200, "Madame Bovary", 25.10));
        documentsList.add(new Document(200, "The Iliad", 27.40));
        documentsList.add(new Document(500, "Lolita", 30.50));
        documentsList.add(new Document(500, "Alice", 32.60));

        filesList.add(new File("/src/aas/documents/Ulysses.txt"));
        filesList.add(new File("/src/aas/documents/MobyDick.txt"));
        filesList.add(new File("/src/aas/documents/Hamlet.txt"));
        filesList.add(new File("/src/aas/documents/Oddysey.txt"));
        filesList.add(new File("/src/aas/documents/GreatGatsby.txt"));
        filesList.add(new File("/src/aas/documents/DivineComedy.txt"));
        filesList.add(new File("/src/aas/documents/MadameBovary.txt"));
        filesList.add(new File("/src/aas/documents/Iliad.txt"));
        filesList.add(new File("/src/aas/documents/Lolita.txt"));
        filesList.add(new File("/src/aas/documents/Alica.txt"));
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
            try(Socket clientSocket = this.clientSocket;
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream()))
            {
                String line;
                while (true) {
                    line = in.readUTF();
                    if(line.equals("retrieveDocuments")) {
                        objOut.writeObject(documentsList);
                        objOut.flush();
                    }
                    else if(line.equals("buyDocument№")) {
                        int docNum = in.readInt();
                        if(docNum < 1 || docNum > documentsList.size()) {
                            System.out.println("You have entered a wrong document number");
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (in.readUTF().equals("Validation")) {
                            objOut.writeObject(filesList.get(docNum - 1));
                            objOut.flush();
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println("There is not enough money");
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (line.equals("amIAdmin?")) {
                    }
                    else if (line.startsWith("/quit")) {
                        break;
                    }

                }

                out.writeUTF("*** Bye " + " ***");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                disconnect();
        }
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Disconnected");
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }
    }


}

public class VClient {
    private static Socket socket = null;
    private static DataInputStream in = null;
    private static DataOutputStream out = null;
    private static Scanner keyboard = null;
    private static ObjectInputStream objIn = null;
    private static List<Document> documentsList;
    private static double account;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String address = "127.0.0.1";
        account = 100.00;
        boolean isListInitialized = false;
        try {
            InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(address);
            socket = new Socket(ipAddress, 2222);
            try {
                keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                objIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                String line;
                while (true) {
                    showMenu();
                    line = keyboard.nextLine();
                    if (isDigit(line)) {
                        int choice = Integer.parseInt(line);
                        if (choice == 1) {
                            out.writeUTF("retrieveDocuments");
                            out.flush();
                            documentsList = (ArrayList<Document>) objIn.readObject();
                            int i = 1;
                            for (Document document : documentsList) {
                                System.out.println(i++ + ": " +  document);
                            }
                            isListInitialized = true;
                        } else if (choice == 2) {
                            if(!isListInitialized) {
                                System.out.println("For the first watch a documents List - choice №1");
                                continue;
                            }
                            System.out.println("Enter the number of document you want to buy");
                            line = keyboard.nextLine();
                            if (isDigit(line)) {
                                if(Integer.valueOf(line) < 1 || Integer.valueOf(line) > documentsList.size()) {
                                    System.out.println("Wrong document index");
                                    continue;
                                }
                                out.writeInt(Integer.valueOf(line));
                                out.flush();
                                account -= documentsList.get(Integer.valueOf(line)).getDocumentPrice();
                                out.writeUTF("Validation");
                                out.flush();
                                File file = (File) objIn.readObject();
                                System.out.println(file);

                            } else {
                                System.out.println("It is a wrong input");
                                continue;
                            }
                        } else if (choice == 3) {
                            out.writeUTF("amIAdmin?");
                            out.flush();
                        } else if (choice == 4) {
                            out.writeUTF("/quit");
                            out.flush();
                            line = in.readUTF();
                            if (line.contains("*** Bye"))
                                break;
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Wrong input. Please re-enter");
                            continue;
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Wrong input. Please re-enter");
                        continue;
                    }


                }
            } finally {
                in.close();
                out.close();
                socket.close();
                objIn.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void showMenu() {
        System.out.println("Enter a number of the menu");
        System.out.println("1: If you want to get document names and costs press 1");
        System.out.println("2: If you want to read the entire contents of the given file press 2");
        System.out.println("3: If you are an admin press 3");
        System.out.println("4: Quit");
    }
    private static boolean isDigit(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(s);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

`DataOutputStream` тут не годится. Объекты типа `File` не содержат никаких данных из файла. Это всего лишь указатель на файл или директорию в файловой системе.

Вам же нужно придумать как передавать имя файла, а потом его содержимое.

Альтернативный вариант - передавать файлы, предварительно помещая их в zip архив и распаковывая на клиенте.

Похожий вопрос уже разбирали тут: [JAVA, передача папки через socket](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/493801).